# how to join multiple tables by using ej function in dolphindb database

Tags: mysql, dolphindb

how to join multiple tables by using ej function in dolphindb database?

I want to join three tables, but seems the function ej can only join two tables. How to join multiple tables in dolphindb database?

Answer (score 0):

You can join two tables by ej, which will return you a new table, then join this new table and t3 by ej. The code is as below:

```py
ej(ej(t1,t2,'id),t3,'id)
```